# Keeping the entryHigh until the position has been filled

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

How can I have this not recalculate the entryHigh while I'm not in a trade? Just the same, initial entryHigh until it enters a trade. THEN calculates to take another trade?

````
    entryHigh := na
    entryLow := na
    strategy.cancel_all()

if (inSession and close[0] < open[0] and barstate.isconfirmed)
    if (strategy.opentrades == 0)
        entryHigh := not na(high[0]) ? high[0] : entryHigh
        strategy.entry("FirstRed", strategy.long, qty=1, limit = entryHigh, stop = entryHigh)```

I've also been trying to do booleans but they're not really working for me...

Like...

```if close[0] < open[0] and barstate.isconfirmed
    tradeCond := true```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can use a flag to set this variable.

Something like below should do:

```
var entryHighSet = false    // This will prevent overwriting entryHigh multiple times
var float entryHigh = na
entryHighSetCondition = false   // Condition to set EntryHigh

is_in_trade = (strategy.position_size != 0)

// Only set entryHigh if
// 1) Not in a in a trade
// 2) Not set already
// 3) Set condition is true
if (not is_in_trade and not entryHighSet and entryHighSetCondition)
    entryHigh := // New value

if (is_in_trade)
    entryHighSet := false   // Reset flag
```